# how to display this data in react with map

Tags: reactjs

[image]How to display the data in the picture using map loop in reactjs.

**Following is the code of Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {
const [blogs,setBlogs]= useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://localhost/blog/blogapi/api/v1/posts')
    .then(res=>{
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data=>{
     console.log(data);
        setBlogs(data);
    })
},[])

return (
    <div className="home">
       {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs" />}  
    </div>

  );
```

}

export default Home;

**Following is the code for BlogList.js**

```
    const BlogList = ({ blogs, title }) => {

return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
            {blogs.map((blog) => {
                 <div className="card" key={blog.id}>
              
                  <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                </div>
        })}

    </div>
);
```

}
export default BlogList;

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing shows up because you are not returning anything inside your map:

It should look more like this:

```
const BlogList = ({ blogs, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      {blogs.map((blog) => {
        return (
          <div className="card" key={blog.id}>
            <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

or this:

```
const BlogList = ({ blogs, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className="card" key={blog.id}>
          <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you want to achieve it is difficult to know what to render specifically but in your example you could so something like this (I have used some example data rather than that in your question but the principle is the same):

```
const data = [
{
id: 1,
title: "Element 1",
content: "Element 1 Content"
},
{
id: 2,
title: "Element 2",
content: "Element 2 Content"
},
{
id: 1,
title: "Element 3",
content: "Element 3 Content"
}
];


const Item = () => {
   return (
      <div className="container">
         {data.map((d) => (
            <h1>{d.title{</h1>
            <p>{d.content}</p>
         ))}
      </div>
}
```

Comment: It doesnot work, i ve explained in details , you can see i have used your approach but it shows nothing